# Duplicate list pattern

Tags: elixir

What will be the best way to duplicate a list pattern limited by a given length?

For example:

Given a pattern `[1,2,3]` and length `7` the result will be `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of is to use `Stream.cycle/1` and `Enum.take/2`:

```
iex(1)> [1, 2, 3] |> Stream.cycle() |> Enum.take(7)
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1]
```